# How do I read the source code without access to file

Tags: php

i want to ask if it is possible to read the php sourcecode (without access to file.inc) of an included file and/or single function? example

### file.inc

```
function thatIsMyFunction( $a ){
  $x = $a * 3 / ($a + 7);
  return $x;
}
```

### index.php

```
include_once("../path/file.inc");
// something like that 
var_dump(thatIsMyFunction());
// to see: 
//  $x = $a * 3 / ($a + 7);
//  return $x;
```

Comment: You cannot var_dump functions as far as I know

Comment: No, with include you don't get to see the source code. But anyone being able to include the file via the local file system, will also be able to read its actual content directly using file_get_contents.

Comment: @CBroe yeah true. didn't thought about that opportunity. big thx also up to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can technically see the function content using Reflection, but you must include the file.

```php
function thatIsMyFunction($a) {
    $x = $a * 3 / ($a + 7);
    return $x;
}
 
function function_dump($function) {
    try {
        $func = new ReflectionFunction($function);
    } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return;
    }
 
    $start = $func->getStartLine() - 1;

    $end =  $func->getEndLine() - 1;
 
    $filename = $func->getFileName();
 
    echo implode("", array_slice(file($filename),$start, $end - $start + 1));
}

 
function_dump('thatIsMyFunction');

// will dump
/*
function thatIsMyFunction($a) {
    $x = $a * 3 / ($a + 7);
    return $x;
};
*/
```

Comment: big thx! littel by side question. if you try to do a coworking space on the server to let other coder produce some parts of the webside and how i see chroot + pw encoded parts for functions and other stuff will not work, how would you do that to have a secure mode where the coder could not steal passwords and other stuff from other coder?

Comment: As far I Know, you cannot protected your files from other devs. Even you you block the user permission to read the files, they can still access through `www-data` or whatever user the website is running. I would personally make contracts of non-compete and non-disclosure agreements.

Comment: An alternative would be to make micro-services. They develop a micro-service on a server, you don't have access to their code, but you can connect through an API. They don't have access to your code, but they can connect to your project through an API. But's that a lot of work, a lot of headache, it's expensive...

Comment: thx that you share your knowledge with me/us!